# Old kernel files (initrd.img-4.*-generic) keeps popping up

Tags: apt, dpkg

I carry this problem along since the first time my ubuntu server told me that there is no space left on device. So I've read that old kernels aren't removed automatically and keep taking up space if you do nothing.

And I don't know what I did years ago, I somehow deleted the old files in boot and it worked for the moment.

But since then, every time I try to update something, the update fails with "no space left" errors. And why? Because these old kernel files (initrd.img-*-generic) are somehow back at boot and take up all the space. Even an old 3.13 file is back at boot. I just upgraded to 19.04 and I have a "initrd.img-3.13.0-57-generic" file in boot.

Why is this happening and how can I finally get rid of it?

Best regards,
Billie

Comment: `dpkg purge initrd...` didn't work, but `/var/lib/initramfs-tools/` seems promising. There I can see all those old version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove old files through apt or in some other way?

I recommend the following approach:

First of all, check which kernels have been installed overtime:

`$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-headers`

Once you identified which versions can be removed, purge them (versions listed below shown only as an example):

`$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.19.0-{18,20,21,25}
$ sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.19.0-{18,20,21,25}`

As the last step, update grub configuration:

`$ sudo update-grub2`

Comment: Yes, I did this dozens of times. @N0rbert pointed out a similar problem and I do see all those old version numbers in the `/var/lib/initramfs-tools/` directory. I will simply try to delete them.

Comment: Did the deletion of those numbers in /var/lib/initramfs-tools/ solve your problem? I am checking to make sure that you did not stuck with it.